# How to check if an element of one array is also element of another in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I need to write c++ code to solve homework assignment.  One part of that code should be for loop which will check if an element of one array is also part of another

I tried to achieve this with nested for loops, if-else if-else conditions etc. I also write that code in Python 3, but I need it in c++.

this is code in Python, that can solve this problem:

```py
for x in array:
    if m in array2:
        print m
        break
```

How will this code be translated into c++? And also what is (if it exists) c++ version of Python keyword ***is***? Thank you  in advance.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/

Comment: [std::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) does the job.

Comment: With [std::set_intersection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) you can find all elements that are in both containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is so simple that I will not explain the details.

I am showing 3 different implementations. Please note, the last is a one liner.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

std::vector<int> v1{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
std::vector<int> v2{ 2,4,6,8,10 };

int main() {

    // Solution 1
    std::cout << "\nSolution 1. Values that are in v1 and v2\n";
    // Simple solution
    for (const int i : v1)
        for (const int j : v2)
            if (i == j) std::cout << i << "\n";


    // Solution 2: The C++ solution
    std::cout << "\n\nSolution 2. Values that are in v1 and v2\n";

    // If you want to store the result
    std::vector<int> result{};
    // After this, result contains values that are both in v1 and v2
    set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::back_inserter(result));

    // Debug output
    std::copy(result.begin(), result.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));


    // Solution 3: The C++ all in one solution
    std::cout << "\n\nSolution 3. Values that are in v1 and v2\n";

    // One-liner
    set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```